# Track changes in database structure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

There has been a change in our DB and one of the SPs has been deleted. We have no idea who did it or when.

Is there any way to find it out?
Or enabling an option to be able to track this in future?

Comment: The "when" could be resolved by checking all backups (an idea from a no-DBA)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are couple of ways to do such forensic analysis :

1. **Using Default trace** (provided that the default trace is running). The default trace create 5 *.TRC file that are recycled when they arrive to 20 MB size. :

   ```
   -- create a test procedure .. so that we can drop it
   use test_kin
   go
   create procedure usp_ABOUT_TO_DELETE 
   as
   select name from sysobjects
   where type = 'U'
   order by name 

   -- now drop the procedure
   drop procedure usp_ABOUT_TO_DELETE
   ```

   [image]

   Below is the sql to get details out of the default trace :

   ```
            /*
             Object Altered
             Object Created
             Object Deleted 
             */

   SELECT TE.NAME
       ,v.subclass_name
       ,DB_NAME(t.DatabaseId) AS DBName
       ,T.NTDomainName
       ,t.NTUserName
       ,t.HostName
       ,t.ApplicationName
       ,t.LoginName
       ,t.Duration
       ,t.StartTime
       ,t.ObjectName
       ,CASE t.ObjectType
           WHEN 8259
               THEN 'Check Constraint'
           WHEN 8260
               THEN 'Default (constraint or standalone)'
           WHEN 8262
               THEN 'Foreign-key Constraint'
           WHEN 8272
               THEN 'Stored Procedure'
           WHEN 8274
               THEN 'Rule'
           WHEN 8275
               THEN 'System Table'
           WHEN 8276
               THEN 'Trigger on Server'
           WHEN 8277
               THEN '(User-defined) Table'
           WHEN 8278
               THEN 'View'
           WHEN 8280
               THEN 'Extended Stored Procedure'
           WHEN 16724
               THEN 'CLR Trigger'
           WHEN 16964
               THEN 'Database'
           WHEN 16975
               THEN 'Object'
           WHEN 17222
               THEN 'FullText Catalog'
           WHEN 17232
               THEN 'CLR Stored Procedure'
           WHEN 17235
               THEN 'Schema'
           WHEN 17475
               THEN 'Credential'
           WHEN 17491
               THEN 'DDL Event'
           WHEN 17741
               THEN 'Management Event'
           WHEN 17747
               THEN 'Security Event'
           WHEN 17749
               THEN 'User Event'
           WHEN 17985
               THEN 'CLR Aggregate Function'
           WHEN 17993
               THEN 'Inline Table-valued SQL Function'
           WHEN 18000
               THEN 'Partition Function'
           WHEN 18002
               THEN 'Replication Filter Procedure'
           WHEN 18004
               THEN 'Table-valued SQL Function'
           WHEN 18259
               THEN 'Server Role'
           WHEN 18263
               THEN 'Microsoft Windows Group'
           WHEN 19265
               THEN 'Asymmetric Key'
           WHEN 19277
               THEN 'Master Key'
           WHEN 19280
               THEN 'Primary Key'
           WHEN 19283
               THEN 'ObfusKey'
           WHEN 19521
               THEN 'Asymmetric Key Login'
           WHEN 19523
               THEN 'Certificate Login'
           WHEN 19538
               THEN 'Role'
           WHEN 19539
               THEN 'SQL Login'
           WHEN 19543
               THEN 'Windows Login'
           WHEN 20034
               THEN 'Remote Service Binding'
           WHEN 20036
               THEN 'Event Notification on Database'
           WHEN 20037
               THEN 'Event Notification'
           WHEN 20038
               THEN 'Scalar SQL Function'
           WHEN 20047
               THEN 'Event Notification on Object'
           WHEN 20051
               THEN 'Synonym'
           WHEN 20549
               THEN 'End Point'
           WHEN 20801
               THEN 'Adhoc Queries which may be cached'
           WHEN 20816
               THEN 'Prepared Queries which may be cached'
           WHEN 20819
               THEN 'Service Broker Service Queue'
           WHEN 20821
               THEN 'Unique Constraint'
           WHEN 21057
               THEN 'Application Role'
           WHEN 21059
               THEN 'Certificate'
           WHEN 21075
               THEN 'Server'
           WHEN 21076
               THEN 'Transact-SQL Trigger'
           WHEN 21313
               THEN 'Assembly'
           WHEN 21318
               THEN 'CLR Scalar Function'
           WHEN 21321
               THEN 'Inline scalar SQL Function'
           WHEN 21328
               THEN 'Partition Scheme'
           WHEN 21333
               THEN 'User'
           WHEN 21571
               THEN 'Service Broker Service Contract'
           WHEN 21572
               THEN 'Trigger on Database'
           WHEN 21574
               THEN 'CLR Table-valued Function'
           WHEN 21577
               THEN 'Internal Table (For example, XML Node Table, Queue Table.)'
           WHEN 21581
               THEN 'Service Broker Message Type'
           WHEN 21586
               THEN 'Service Broker Route'
           WHEN 21587
               THEN 'Statistics'
           WHEN 21825
               THEN 'User'
           WHEN 21827
               THEN 'User'
           WHEN 21831
               THEN 'User'
           WHEN 21843
               THEN 'User'
           WHEN 21847
               THEN 'User'
           WHEN 22099
               THEN 'Service Broker Service'
           WHEN 22601
               THEN 'Index'
           WHEN 22604
               THEN 'Certificate Login'
           WHEN 22611
               THEN 'XMLSchema'
           WHEN 22868
               THEN 'Type'
           ELSE 'Hmmm???'
           END AS ObjectType
   FROM [fn_trace_gettable](CONVERT(VARCHAR(150), (
                   SELECT TOP 1 value
                   FROM [fn_trace_getinfo](NULL)
                   WHERE [property] = 2
                   )), DEFAULT) T
   INNER JOIN sys.trace_events TE ON T.EventClass = TE.trace_event_id
   INNER JOIN sys.trace_subclass_values v ON v.trace_event_id = TE.trace_event_id
       AND v.subclass_value = t.EventSubClass
   WHERE TE.NAME IN (
           'Object:Created'
           ,'Object:Deleted'
           ,'Object:Altered'
           )
       -- filter statistics created by SQL server                                         
       AND t.ObjectType NOT IN (21587)
       -- filter tempdb objects
       AND DatabaseID <> 2
       -- get only events in the past 24 hours
       AND StartTime > DATEADD(HH, - 24, GETDATE())
   ORDER BY t.StartTime DESC;
   ```
2. **Digging into Transaction log** -- More advance ! Note the use of undocumented **fn_dblog**.

   - Find out the transaction ID

     ```
     SELECT [Current LSN]
     ,Operation
     ,[AllocUnitName]
     ,[Lock Information]
     ,[Transaction ID]
     ,[Description]
     ,[Begin Time]
     ,[Transaction Name]
     ,[Transaction SID]
     FROM fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)
     WHERE [Operation] = N'LOP_DELETE_ROWS'
     AND [AllocUnitName] = N'sys.sysschobjs.clst'
     --- change here for the object name you think got dropped/deleted
     --- can be table, stored procedure, etc
     AND CHARINDEX(cast(N'ABOUT_TO_DELETE' AS VARBINARY(4000)), [Log Record]) > 0
     ```
   - Now find out the transaction based on the above transaction ID:

     ```
                SELECT [Current LSN]
                ,Operation
                ,[AllocUnitName]
                ,[Lock Information]
                ,[Transaction ID]
                ,[Description]
                ,[Begin Time]
                ,[Transaction Name]
                ,SUSER_SNAME([Transaction SID]) as CULPRIT_USER -- WE Got the Cluprit!!
              FROM fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)
              WHERE [Transaction ID] = N'0000:0000026c';
     ```

   [image]

Excellent References :

- [The default trace in SQL Server - the power of performance and security auditing](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-default-trace-in-sql-server---the-power-of-performance-and-security-auditing/)
- [How to read and interpret the SQL Server log](http://rusanu.com/2014/03/10/how-to-read-and-interpret-the-sql-server-log/) by [Remus Rusanu](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/708/remus-rusanu)

Comment: Using your 2nd query, if there was no result, does it mean that *.trc files has been recycled?

Comment: Yes that might be the case. You can use wmi event notification to trigger a trace into a table as well. If you have t-log backups then you can dig in them as well.

Answer (score 7):

For the stored procedure that has already been deleted, the only option is to dig into the online transaction log or transaction log backups (in case the database is in the full recovery model).

The above mentioned **fn_dblog** provides the requested info only if the transaction is still in the online transaction log. To read transaction log backups, use **fn_dump_dblog**. Check out Paul Randal's article:

[Using fn_dblog, fn_dump_dblog, and restoring with STOPBEFOREMARK to an LSN](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/using-fn_dblog-fn_dump_dblog-and-restoring-with-stopbeforemark-to-an-lsn/)

To read the transaction logs (online, detached, and transaction log backups), besides using undocumented functions, you can use a third party tool such as [ApexSQL Log](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-recover-stored-procedures-functions-and-triggers/). It can show who and when deleted the stored procedure, and will also provide the script to re-create it.

[image]

In future, you can also use the [SQL Server Audit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx) feature, just make sure you have specified all events you want to audit.

*Disclaimer: I work for ApexSQL as a support engineer*

Answer (score 6):

For the future you can use a database trigger to log the DDL events.

[SQL Server DDL Triggers to Track All Database Changes](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/)

Comment: You can use extended events/audits too.